# How I can hide those triple-line button when hovering column in AG-GRID

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

When I hover over any column this button shows, and after clicking it I can choose from options, like: Pin column, Auto-size, Reset, ...

How can I disable (hide) it? So that it's not shown when I hover column.
[hover over column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B135D.png)

I'm using Angular app, and Ag-grid Enterprise.

Tried to add:

```
  defaultColDef: ColDef = { 
    enableRowGroup: false,
    enablePivot: false,
    enableValue: false
  };
```

But this 'hamburger' button still there. What should I do?

Comment: Just to confirm, do you only want to hide the hamburger when hovering on a column?  But you still want the menu to be able to be accessed?  Or completely hide the hamburger in all circumstances?

Answer (score 0):

The options are set using [menuTabs](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/column-properties/#reference-header-menuTabs) and can take an array of 0 or more predefined values. If you wish to hide it, update the 'defaultColDef' to this:

```
 defaultColDef = {
    menuTabs: [],
  };
```